# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK starts multiple tasks with the same activity

Tags: android

I have a Notification which starts an Activity B with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) says:

> [...] if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front [...]

In the case that the user taps the Notification while in Home Screen or a different app, this works fine. But if the user is in an Activity of my app, let's say in Activity "A", and then taps the Notification multiple times, Activity "B" is started multiple times. This leads to Back key not bringing back to Activity "A".

What am I doing wrong here? And where's the difference between being in home screen or a different app and being in Activity A of my app?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` for the notification activity. That will make sure that there is only one instance of Activity B, and it is re-used .

The difference is that when your Activity A is in the foreground you already have task running , otherwise (most probably) not. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for more info about tasks.

Comment: But why is my Activity B started multiple times although the doc says "the current task will simply be brought to the front"?

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP solved my issue but still I don't understand what I mentioned above.

Comment: Read the docs on tasks, task and activity are different things.

Comment: I know what tasks and activities are. But what means "then a new activity will not be started" in your opinion? In my opinion, it means, that the activity will not be started again ...

Answer (score 2):

Now I found out that I had to set a different affinity in the manifest to start the Activity in its own task. That solved my problem, too.